# Send file from Client to Server in python

Tags: python, networking, client

I am sending a file from Client to Server in python. For this I've wrote python script. **I want to store the file at receiver side same as the filename that is sent by the sender.** Suppose I am sending file **"First.txt"**. Then at receiver side it is saving with file name **file_1.txt**. Instead of file_1.txt, I want its original name as First.txt. One more thing, if I'm sending another file after First.txt, it is overwriting the previous file at receiver. I'm not getting any idea how to solve this problem.Please help me.

**Server code (Receiver)**

```
import socket
import shutil
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
HOST = ''
PORT = 31401
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(3)
conn, addr = s.accept()                
print 'conn at address',addr
conn.sendall('READY')
i=1
f = open(r'file_'+ str(i)+".txt",'wb')
i=i+1
fsize=int(conn.recv(8))               
print 'File size',fsize
sfile = conn.makefile("rb")
shutil.copyfileobj(sfile, f)
sfile.close()

f.write(conn.recv(fsize))           
f.close()
conn.close()
s.close()
```

**Client Code (Sender)**

```
import socket, os, shutil
from stat import ST_SIZE
HOST = raw_input("Please enter IP-address :  ")

PORT = 31400              
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST,PORT))
if s.recv(8)!='READY':
    raw_input('Unable to connect \n\n Press any key to exit ...')
    s.close()
    exit()
path=raw_input("enter path of file :  ")

f=open(path,'rb')
fsize=os.stat(f.name)[ST_SIZE]


s.sendall(str(fsize).zfill(8))
sfile = s.makefile("wb")
shutil.copyfileobj(f, sfile)
sfile.close()
s.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: Define your problem statement clearly - Do you want the file to get overwritten or not? Do you want to save it as `First(1).txt` or something like that? You need to alter your code accordingly. You should also look at a more robust mechanism maybe starting with serializations, JSON objects etc.

Comment: First of all, I want to save my file at receiver side with its original name and content. If filename is First1.txt, then at receiver, this must save with First1.txt. I want to clear this first.

Comment: You can send a json object over the network which can have the name of the file and the content inside it and then create the file at the receiver accordingly.

Comment: Can you plzz modify my code..?? I dont know about json..I'm new in python.plzzz help me...!!!

Comment: You need to read up on it - http://doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/json/

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194388/how-to-send-file-from-client-to-server-and-save-it-with-same-filename/23195118#23195118